# Invalid use of auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In this code:

```
for ( ;(auto i = std::find(some_string.begin(),some_string.end(),'%')) != some_string.end();)
    {

    }
```

I'm getting error from gcc 4.7.1:

```
error: invalid use of 'auto'|
```

any ideas why? shouldn't that be correctly compiled?

Comment: There's no need to assign anything here. Just remove `auto i =` and leave the rest, it should then work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with `auto`. You just cannot declare variables in random places, for example this will not compile either - an equivalent of what you were trying to do, but without `auto`:

```
int main() {
  for ( ; (int i = 0) != 1; ++i)
    ;   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: He can probably use `for (auto i; i = std::find; ){ //do_something(); }`

Comment: @Spidey or he can he just take out the variable declaration completely. `for ( ; std::find( .. ) != somestring.end(); )`.. As a matter of fact just make a while loop: `while (std::find(some_string.begin(),some_string.end(),'%') != some_string.end())` ...

Comment: He might be using the variable inside the loop. That's why I kept the variable.

Comment: @Spidey: And what should the type of `auto` deduce to in that case?

Comment: @Spidey: (Use @username to respond so I get notified.) My point was that use of `auto` is not valid. Try this program out and see: `int main() { auto i; i = 5; }` The type of the variable must be known at its declaration, but without an initializer `auto` cannot deduce the type. Your example solution is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a loop, you'll only ever find the first '%'. You need to resume searching from i, not some_string.begin() to find subsequent '%'.

```
auto i = std::find(some_string.begin(), some_string.end(), '%'));
while (i != some_string.end()) {
    // Your code here.

    i = std::find(i, some_string.end(), '%'));  // Find next '%'.
}
```